# How to fix "Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not exist" in Laravel after deployment to Ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, lamp

I am currently hosting an application on a ubuntu 16.04 server... but when i try to deploy the same code on fresh ubuntu 18.04 server i get the following error on my apache logs

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not exist in /var/www/xxxxxxxxxxxx/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:788

navigating to that line of code on my laravel project was

```php
$reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
```

I cleared the config in bootstrap/cache and ran composer dump-autoload to no avail

Comment: Please edit the question and add the `config/app.php` file

Comment: Are they running the same version of PHP?

Comment: you need to go through the stacktrace to see what is actually trying to resolve 'view' from the container as it appears it isn't bound yet

Answer (score 11):

run this command in project root :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the following folders are writable:

- `bootstrap/cache`
- `storage/framework/views`

Answer (score 6):

The answer is to run `composer dump-autoload -o`. Notice the `-o`.

Comment: what does `-o` stand for?

Comment: @Sliq optimized dump

Comment: Can you please explain why this works ??
Like it worked for me, but I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help guys the issue is that I never had composer installed on the server all along. Installing composer on the server fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Composer wasn't the answer for me as the server deploy method just called for copying the entire folder the server where composer was installed.

What fixed it for me was installing `php-mysql`, I had forgotten to install during server setup.

I presume the error about the missing view was either a read-herring, or a previously undiscovered problem with the project error handling